# Stop Refresh data of Repeater on add new row

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Below is my code to insert rows in datatable and then i bind datatable to repeater :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                if (ViewState["cnt"] != null)
                {
                    ViewState["cnt"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["cnt"]) + 1;
                    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("SrNo", typeof(int));
                    dt.Columns.Add("VisaType", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Nationality", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("DOB", typeof(DateTime));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PassportNo", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PassportExpDate", typeof(DateTime));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PP1", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PP2", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Photo", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Rate", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("NoOfApplicant", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("TotalAmnt", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Table", typeof(int));
                    int SrNO = 1;
                    for (int j = 1; j <= Convert.ToInt32(drpNoOfApplicant.SelectedValue); j++)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(j, drpVisaDuration.SelectedItem.Text, RadCountry.Text, null, null, "Male", null, null, null, null, null, txtVisaAmount.Text, drpNoOfApplicant.SelectedValue, txtTotalAmount.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["cnt"]));
                        SrNO += SrNO;
                    }
                    DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
                    dt.Merge(dt1);
                    RptApplicant.DataSource = dt;
                    RptApplicant.DataBind();

                    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                    //Session["dt"] = dt;
                    //txtVisaType.Text = drpVisaDuration.SelectedItem.Text;
                    //txtNationality.Text = txtNationalityCustomer.Text;
                    txtNoOfApplicant.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewState["cnt"] = 0;

                    dt.Columns.Add("SrNo", typeof(int));
                    dt.Columns.Add("VisaType", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Nationality", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("DOB", typeof(DateTime));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PassportNo", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PassportExpDate", typeof(DateTime));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PP1", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("PP2", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Photo", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Rate", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("NoOfApplicant", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("TotalAmnt", typeof(string));
                    dt.Columns.Add("Table", typeof(int));
                    int SrNO = 1;
                    for (int j = 1; j <= Convert.ToInt32(drpNoOfApplicant.SelectedValue); j++)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(j, drpVisaDuration.SelectedItem.Text, RadCountry.Text, null, null, "Male", null, null, null, null, null, txtVisaAmount.Text, drpNoOfApplicant.SelectedValue, txtTotalAmount.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["cnt"]));
                        SrNO += SrNO;
                    }
                    RptApplicant.DataSource = dt;
                    RptApplicant.DataBind();

                    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                    //Session["dt"] = dt;
                    //txtVisaType.Text = drpVisaDuration.SelectedItem.Text;
                    //txtNationality.Text = txtNationalityCustomer.Text;
                    txtNoOfApplicant.Text = "";
                }
```

Now when i add new row the data which was fill get refresh, here i want to stop refresh that data. i am stuck in this code, Pls reply me.[image]

Comment: can you show your Page_Load method ?  where you bind your repeater in you code ?

Comment: i bind repeater on click of select button and code is mention above

Comment: By default, `<asp:Buttons` will cause a PostBack, although if you have `ViewState` enabled, controls on the page should retain their state after the server roundtrip. To prevent the PostBack, you could e.g. use a normal browser side `<button type="button"`, or otherwise use an Ajax Update panel to just do a partial mini refresh.

Comment: currently the repeater and button row is in update panel

Comment: We'll need to see the relevant `.aspx` please

Comment: its very long code to display here